# prevent json of my command object from comming down to client during post

Tags: spring-mvc

My controller has following calls

```
@ModelAttribute("commandObject")
public UsersCommand getCommand(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
    ...
    return command;
}


@RequestMapping(value = {"addusers.json"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void handleGet() {
        //empty method
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"addusers.json"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handlePost(@ModelAttribute("commandObject") UsersCommand command, HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception {
    //do stuff
}
```

during the get i get the json of my UsersCommand object, however after I do a post, I am getting the json of my command object which i do not need as i want to do a fire and forget post.

How can I avoid the json object from coming down to browser during post?

Comment: Hi can you elaborate about this mapping 
just curious how this mapping works . I was aware of value="/path" . What does (value = {"addusers.json"} signify.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you're code does. I can't think of how your `get` method does anything. Are you leaving out the method body?

Comment: @steve.hanson: The get method does not have any implementation. I am still a noobie and learning delicate intricacy of spring and not sure what the `handleGet` does, seems like it may not doing anything. I am trying to determine as to how `getCommand` gets called when I invoke my controller from the jsp page via ajax call. The ajax call only calls my controller as `http://mylocalhost/addusers.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you only want JSON returned with the GET method. To do this, remove the `@ModelAttribute` method all-together. This tells Spring to add the return object to your model on every handler in the controller, which you don't want. Then modify your GET handler to be like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"addusers.json"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public UserCommand handleGet() {
    UserCommand cmd = getUserCommand();
    return cmd;
}
```

The `@ResponseBody` annotation tells Spring to serialize the return type to JSON (or XML if you annotated your class with JAXB, and depending on the request accept headers). For this to work, you also need to add Jackson to your classpath and make sure you're using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableWebMvc` in your XML or Java config, respectively.

This will sound like self-promotion, but I wrote a post about this if you want more detail: http://codetutr.com/2013/04/09/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody/.

Hope that's helpful! Let me know if I can add any more clarity for you.

Comment: In fiddler i see the response in the xml tab rather then json tab.

Comment: What is the content of the response and the response status header? Are you getting "200 OK", and is the json object coming back?

Comment: i do get 200. do not get json back.content-type is `application/xml`

Comment: Have you updated your code as it is in my answer? Can you update your question with the code you have now?

Comment: had to use `produces="application/json"`